# Ayuda con herencia en Java, heredar variables

Tags: java, poo

hoy vengo porque tengo un problema y llevo casi toda la mañana rompiendome la cabeza y no logro nada. Lo que pasa es que en el siguiente codigo quiero hereder las variables X,Y (con sus numeros) pero no me deja ya que no tengo acceso a variables en privado.

```
class Cuadrilatero {

private double P1;
private double P2;
private double P3;
private double P4;

private double x1,x2,x3,x4,y1,y2,y3,y4;


public Cuadrilatero() {
}

public Cuadrilatero(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, double x3, double y3, double x4, double y4){
    setP1(x1, y1);
    setP2(x2, y2);
    setP3(x3, y3);
    setP4(x4, y4);
}

//creación de los puntos

public void setP1(double x1, double y1){
    this.x1=x1;
    this.y1=y1;
}


public void setP2(double x2, double y2){
    this.x2=x2;
    this.y2=y2;
} 

public void setP3(double x3, double y3){
    this.x3=x3;
    this.y3=y3;
}


public void setP4(double x4, double y4){
    this.x4=x4;
    this.y4=y4;
}
```

}

Esta es la clase principal y donde quiero heredar es la siguiente.

```
class Trapezoide extends Cuadrilatero{

private double baseMe;
private double baseMa;
private double altura;


    public Trapezoide(){
    }

    public Trapezoide(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, double x3, double y3, double x4, double y4){
        super(x1,  y1,  x2,  y2, x3,  y3, x4,  y4);
    }

    public Trapezoide(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, double x3, double y3, double x4, double y4,double baseMe, double baseMa, double altura){
        setBaseMe(baseMe);
        setBaseMa(baseMa);
        setAltura(altura);
    }

    public void setBaseMe(double baseMe){
        this.baseMe=baseMe;
    }

    public double getBaseMe(){
        baseMe=x3-x2;
        return baseMe;
    }

    public void setBaseMa(double baseMa){
        this.baseMa=baseMa;

    }

    public double getBaseMa(){
        baseMa=x4-x1;
        return baseMa;
    }

    public void setAltura(double altura){
        this.altura=altura;
    }

    public double getAltura(){
        altura=y2-y1;
        return altura;
    }

    public double getArea(){
        double area;
        area= ((getBaseMa() + getBaseMe()) + getAltura())/2;
        return area;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "El area del [Trapezoide] es: " + getArea() + " cuadrados";
    }
```

}

Como podría hacerle para hereder eso? gracias

Comment: No las pongas como privadas, ponlas como protected, lo que permite que solo clases hijas puedan usar las variables.

Comment: La herencia no permite heredar variables con el modificador`public`.

Comment: Deberías más bien revisar la lógica de tu programa. Si la clase tiene variables privadas las cuales puedes modificar mediante los métodos `setter`, se supone que creas una instancia de esa clase allí donde necesitas las variables. Mediante dicha instancia modificas mediante los `setter`  el valor de las variables, y si los quieres usar, entonces puedes dotar a tu clase de métodos `getter` que te permitan acceder a los valores de dichas variables. De ese modo estarías respetando la norma conocida como *encapsulación*, uno de los fundamentos de la POO.

Answer (score 1):

Usa el modificador de acceso `protected` al declarar propiedades en la clase padre para que puedas usarlas en sus clases hijas (en caso de que quieras que ese sea su comportamiento), al usar `private` en este caso, simplemente estás restringiendo el acceso a esas propiedades de manera que solo la clase padre puede acceder a ellas. Luego de heredar la clase padre con sus propiedades protegidas podrás acceder a ellas fácilmente a través de `this`.

Un ejemplo sencillo:

```
class Perro {
    protected String nombre;
    protected String raza;

    public Perro(String nombre, String raza) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.raza = raza;
    }
}

class PastorAleman extends Perro {
    public PastorAleman(String nombre) {
        super(nombre, "Pastor Alemán");
    }

    public String getInfo() {
        return this.nombre + " es un " + this.raza;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PastorAleman aquiles = new PastorAleman("Aquiles");
        System.out.println(aquiles.getInfo());
    }
}

// Console output:
// Aquiles es un Pastor Alemán
```

Alternativamente podrías encapsular las propiedades privadas de la clase padre y acceder a ellas a través de sus respectivos `getter` y `setter`.